# Can women put their pics (with hijab) on internet?

Tags: halal-haram, women, hijab, image, photos

I've already inquired for a similar question, but my previous question was in regards to "Can women put their pictures (without hijab) on the internet". So, at that question I concluded that it is impermissible for women to utilize their photographs without hijab in cyberspace, since haram is haram (and it can has its negative effect [sin] on the viewer) and ...

But about the ones whose images are with hijab, I assume: since there can be existed the probability of an amount of sin (as a possibility) for the ones who watch her(them) as non-mahrams, I was wondering if **it is permissible, Makruh or impermissible for women to utilize that if their photos are with hijab**?

Answer (score -1):

I was told by a scholar this is not a good idea as a non-mahram can enjoy her face as much as he wants (she isn't going to catch him staring at her for 3 hours!) and zoom in etc.

Comment: Firstly, you'd better expand your answer + ref. as much as possible. Secondly, I appreciate your short helpful answer, especially you mentioned a notable/important issue that "a non mahram can enjoy her face as much as he wants", yeah, it is de facto true, a significant point, God bless you for pointing it out.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].